# Letter of Rav Yechezkel Landau

Tags: product-recommendation, rabbis, internet, historical-figures

There was a letter written by Rav Yechezkel Landau to the followers of Reb Yonason Eibeshitz after the whole debacle between their leader and Reb Yaakov Emden. I have seen a few English versions of this letter, but I wanted to see the original text.

Where can I read this letter online?

What piqued my interest was from the language used, it seems Rav Landau implicated guilt on the part of Rav Eibeshitz leveled against him by Rav Emden of being a secret Sabatian. In spite of this, he told Rav Eibeshitz' followers not to leave him, as he is a holy learned man.

I would like to see the original myself to see if this is in fact what was written.

Comment: Contact Professor Shneur Leiman, I'm sure he knows the whereabouts of this letter. he lives in queens, so check him up there, he goes by Sid leiman. try this email address: sleiman@brooklyn.cuny.edu

Comment: Where did you see this letter in English?

Comment: @wfb In the artscroll Great Jewish Letters. http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422609538.html one other place also quoted it in passing, but i don't recall offhand where that was.

Comment: @Mefaresh thank you for the tip. I emailed him, now let's see what happens.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance. You will probably appreciate this article by the aforementioned prof leiman http://leimanlibrary.com/texts_of_publications/48.%20When%20a%20Rabbi%20is%20Accused%20of%20Heresy%20-%20R.%20Ezekiel%20Landau.pdf

Comment: @wfb wow. All I can say is wow and thanks again. In footnote 21 he discusses issues surrounding the original text.

Comment: I cannot parse "Rav Landau implicated guilt on the part of Rav Eibeshitz leveled against him by Rav Emden of being a secret Sabatian".

Comment: @msh210. What's shver?

Comment: As noted in the article, evidence of the newly discovered amulets indicates that that Eibeschuz's detractors were correct; he was a Sabbatean. Accordingly, rather than be surprised by those who said and wrote explicitly that he was a Sabbatean, or those like R. Landau, who implied he might have been, surprise ought to be leveled at any (who saw the amulets) yet thought he was not.

Comment: @mevaqesh my surprise was at telling the students to stay with their Rabbi AFTER coming to the conclusion that he was a sabatean. As far as why nobody else wanted to see the truth, he was apparently the single greatest Rabbi of the time. Much 'bigger' than the Yaavetz, as far as educating students who went on to become community leaders themselves goes. It's safe to say he had a much larger impact on Judaism to this day than three Yaavetz did. I can understand fully why nobody wanted to believe it then. Till today sanitized Jewish history books won't admit it.

Comment: @user6591 Ah ha. (Just to clarify I think there was nothing unreasonable with those who did not see the contents of the amulets defending him.)